# Complicated Unique Domain setup needed DNS/htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, shopify

I have a unique challenge hopefully someone smart here can help with!

Situation

Old established Domain acquired and 301 Redirected to new Domain
Survival-warehouse.com > SurvivalWarehouse.co

At the old domain existed an old magento install, with well google indexed pages. We did not have server access to saved all html pages locally and have uploaded to new server on the new domain

So at new domain SurvivalWarehouse.com exists html product pages that are indexed and rank reasonably in google, we don't want to lose this
Examples:

https://survivalwarehouse.co/food-storage-survival-food-emergency-food/emergency-food-supply-kits/value-buckets.html

https://survivalwarehouse.co/mre-meals-ready-to-eat3214.html?___store=default

What I'd like to do is keep the html pages LIVE and serving. BUT here's the complex issue
I'd like to use Shopify as the front end when you call up the root domain https://survivalwarehouse.co

But still have the old pages exist and serve.

Shopify does not allow for htaccess, or uploads of html files. But requires a full domain redirect to it's server.

How can I get

https://SurvivalWarehouse.co to serve to shopify fully
Yet have the old html pages still serve based on their current and indexed urls?

don't want to or can't use a sub domain as I don't want to lose the 301 redirect juice/domain authority and backlinks that are currently redirected from old domain to new, and google views each subdomain as a unique domain.

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise!

Hopefully I didn't garble this too much

Comment: If Shopify requires that your domain points to their server via the DNS, then there is little you can do in terms of rewriting, from your end. **All** requests made to _any_ URLs with that domain name will be made directly towards their server.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it seems to be a rather tough technical issue.. without any really apparent solution..but I welcome any and all ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your old SEO juice by making your new domain and Shopify handle them. So for any old content you like, just ensure you have a copy of that working well in your new Shopify theme and store. Once you do, you can make a redirect in Shopify so that if someone bookmarked the old domain and old HTML, they would get redirected to the same content in the Shopify. That is how it works.

Comment: If i'm understanding you properly....you can not create or have .html pages on the shopify platform

Comment: Shopify is nothing but HTML, CSS and JS. So of course you can have HTML pages. You just cannot have Shopify the platform render some HTML on some other system.